# After build webrtc for android, libjingle_peerconnection_java.jar becoming empty

Tags: javascript, android, webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I want to build webRtc for android. I find a build script([script](https://github.com/pristineio/webrtc-build-scripts)) and I can build webRtc sucsessful. But after build webrtc, libjingle_peerconnection_java.jar include only one class(Empty.class).Why is it becomming empty ? I followed the steps below and I didn't get any errors. I use Ubuntu. **sourceandroid/build.sh after **install_dependencies after **get_webrtc after **export WEBRTC_DEBUG=true and **export WEBRTC_ARCH=armv76.prepare_gyp_defines &&execute_build

Thanks.